# Jsfiddle for debugging does not run with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a JSfiddle so that I can debug a problem with the developer of Vue.Draggable but I cannot get Vuetify to work. I would like to display the v-autocomplete.

What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/legionNL/pqzwy4vt/2/

```
<div id="app">
  <v-autocomplete v-model="actions" :items="UnitsAndBuildings" 
chips item-value="action" item-text="action" multiple></v-autocomplete>
  <v-chip outlined pill class="ma-2">Default</v-chip>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get rid of this:

```js
components: {
  draggable
},
```

`draggable` isn't defined so that'll nuke the whole thing. I believe the CDN version will be registered globally anyway.

Second problem is your resources order. Expand the resources section on the left-hand side and reorder them to be in the appropriate order. `vue.js` should be first.

Next problem is the old version of Vue. You're pointing at 2.4.2. Update that to 2.6.10.

Next up, register Vuetify like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
```

Get rid of the `Vue.use(Vuetify)`.

Finally, you're pointing at an ancient CSS file for Vuetify. Update the version to match the JS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to Vue so I was struggling for eternity trying to get my development problem into the JSfiddle. 

@ittus also thanks for the demo I was able to get it to work now with some changes and adding some resources.